Persistent BottomSheet in Flutter
I am beginner here. i want to combine the features of these two bottom-sheets like i want to have a bottom sheet that is draggable but not close ->on scroll down and using back button but i also want to have a feature of (persistent bottomsheet i.e interacting with background without closing the bottomsheet) .Actually i want user to interact with the rest of app and not close the bottom sheet on backpress and scroll down. I dont know whether i have explained my problem clearly or not my english is not that good.
I have dismiss the scroll down close functionality but the back buttom and the interacting with the rest of app is not solved i tried many solutions but not created custom one. i dont want to use that. i want to know iff there is any parametr that make it possible.

can you share a demo or something?

Thank you, @MunsifAli ! I’ve resolved the issue. I genuinely appreciate you taking the time to read my post and offering your help.

You're welcome, @Hafsa Awan Glad you resolved it. Please consider posting your solution on StackOverflow to help others too!

@MunsifAli sure i will share my solution soon.
